# Does SharePoint List have the ability to control field edit access by user or by a status field?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to use SharePoint Online to create a SharePoint List (say ListA),
in this ListA there are quite a few fields (say 30 fields),
one of these fields is the Status field, its value could be Open, WIP, Review, Closed.
There have multiple users (say UserA, UserB and UserC) can view all fields of all the items in ListA.

My 5 questions are, can this ListA in SharePoint Online achieve below objectives?

1. Only allow UserA to create new items; all users can view all items
2. Only allow UserA to delete items in Status Open, if Status is not Open then UserA cannot delete this item
3. Only allow UserA to edit first 10 fields (Field1 to Field10); Only allow UserB to edit Field11 to Field20; Only allow UserC to edit last 10 fields (Field21 to Field30)
4. Only allow to edit first 10 fields (Field1 to Field10) when Status is Open; Only allow to edit Field11 to Field20 when Status is WIP; Only allow to edit last 10 fields (Field21 to Field30) when Status is Review; when Status is Closed all fields become view only, no user could edit any field.
5. In the view or edit form, show first 10 fields on the left hand side placed from top to bottom; show Field11 to Field20 in the center from top to bottom; show last 10 fields on the right hand side from top to bottom, as below:

Field1          Field11          Field21

Field2          Field12          Field22

...             ...              ...

Field9          Field19          Field29

Field10         Field20          Field30

If any one of the above 5 questions is feasible, please provide related reference link(s) or your solution(s) for it.

If it was impossible (not supported in SharePoint Online), please also let me know.

Many thanks

J.W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the solutions for your Requirements

1.Yes. Give user A edit permissions while others read permissions. Refer to this article about SP permission levels:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels

2.Yes.Use SharePoint designer to create a workflow to change the user permissions. 
Check this article :https://truapps.portalfront.com/how-toset-sharepoint-item-level-permissions-based-on-column-or-field-values.html

3 and 4 No. It's impossible to set column/field level permission in SharePoint

5.Yes. Use InfoPath to create custom forms.

Comment: thanks for your reply, re your answer 5, since I need to use SharePoint Online, is PowerApps a better option for creating custom forms?

Comment: If you are using modern experience, use PowApps to create custom forms. InfoPath is for classic experience.